# Sorting is not working for my WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I have a Datagrid.Sorting is not working for it.

I do not know where the problem is.I searched for it.

I did not find solutions.

My code is

```
<toolkit:DataGrid Name="TSGrid" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                                  SelectionChanged="TSGrid_SelectionChanged" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" 
                                  RowHeight="25"
                                  ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" FontSize="12" 
                                  BorderBrush="DarkGreen" BorderThickness="1" ColumnHeaderHeight="30" 
                                  IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                                  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="True" SelectionMode="Single"
                                  SelectionUnit="FullRow" CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
                                  AreRowDetailsFrozen="False" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}"
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" LoadingRow="TSGrid_LoadingRow" Margin="4,0,0,4">
```

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance

Ramki

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `CanUserSortColumns` property of DataGrid to `True`

Comment: By default CanUserSortColumns=True.I tried it.But when i click on Headers it did not work

Comment: Then you need to assign property path to SortMemberPath

Answer (score 0):

if previous answers didn't work for you check below link , the idea is to define the sorting in the level of the collectionViewSource
[WPF DataGrid default sort not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985125/wpf-datagrid-default-sort-not-working)